# Prove that $\mathrm S_m\cdot p=\{p\}\iff p=\sum_{[\alpha]\in \Bbb N^m/\mathrm S_m}p_{[\alpha]}\left(\sum_{\beta\in [\alpha]}X^\beta\right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let $R$ a commutative ring with unity and $\mathrm S_m$ is the set of permutations over $m$ positions, with $m\in\Bbb N$.

A polynomial $p\in R[X_1,...,X_m]$ is called symmetric if $\sigma(p)=p$ for all $\sigma\in\mathrm S_m$, where any polynomial is defined as

$$p:=\sum_{\alpha\in\Bbb N^m} p_{\alpha}X^\alpha\tag{1}$$

where $p_\alpha\in R$ is the coefficient for

$$X^\alpha:=X_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot X_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots X_m^{\alpha_m}$$

> Prove that $p$ is symmetric if and only if have the form
>
> $$p=\sum_{[\alpha]\in \Bbb N^m/\mathrm S_m}p_{[\alpha]}\left(\sum_{\beta\in [\alpha]}X^\beta\right)\tag{2}$$

Where $\alpha\in \Bbb N^m$ and $\Bbb N^m/ \mathrm S_m$ is the set of equivalence classes such that

$$\alpha\sim\beta\iff \beta\in\mathrm S_m\cdot\alpha=[\alpha]\tag{3}$$

and

$$\sigma\cdot \alpha :=\sigma(\alpha)=\langle\alpha_{\sigma(1)},\alpha_{\sigma(2)},...,\alpha_{\sigma(m)}\rangle\tag{4}$$

and $p_{[\alpha]}\in R$ is the coefficient for all $X^\beta$ such that $\beta\in[\alpha]$. And the permutation over a polynomial is defined as

$$\sigma\cdot\sum_\alpha p_\alpha X^\alpha := \sum_\alpha p_\alpha X^{\sigma\cdot\alpha}\tag{5}$$

---

Check my proof please.

**Part one $(\implies)$**

If $p,q$ are two polynomials then $p=q$ if and only if $p_\alpha=q_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in \Bbb N^m$. Then checking $(5)$ we have that

$$\sum_\alpha p_\alpha X^\alpha = \sum_\alpha p_\alpha X^{\sigma\cdot\alpha}\iff p_\alpha=p_{\sigma^{-1}\cdot\alpha}$$

and $p$ will be symmetric if the above holds for all $\sigma\in\mathrm S_m$, i.e $p_\alpha$ must be the same for all equivalent $\alpha$ under any permutation.

Then we took $p_\beta=p_{[\alpha]}$ if $\beta\sim\alpha$ as described in $(3)$, and finally we get $(2)$.

**Part two $(\impliedby)$**

Cause $\sum_{\beta\in [\alpha]}X^\beta$ is the collection of all possible permutations of $\alpha$ then

$$\sum_{\beta\in [\alpha]}X^{\sigma\cdot\beta}=\sum_{\beta\in [\alpha]}X^\beta$$

i.e. the expression $(2)$ is invariant under the action of $\mathrm S_m$, then $p$ is symmetric.

---

**Questions:**

- I dont know if this proof is enough formalized, I feel like it is so wordy and the fundamental facts are hard to formalize properly. Some advice about proof writing will be welcome.
- I dont see any specific reason for $R$ to be commutative, can you enlighten me here?

Comment: Your proof is correct. Yes, it could be more formalized (in the $\Longrightarrow$ direction, you might want to explain why $p$ has the form (2)), but it is fairly clear already. One thing you can improve very quickly is that you should define the $S_m$-action on the $m$-tuples first, *then* the equivalence relation $\sim$, *then* the equivalence classes, rather than stuff them all into one sentence.

Comment: Does $R$ have to be commutative? No, and it doesn't even have to be a ring. Any $\mathbb{Z}$-module would work here. (As long as $R\left[X_1, \ldots, X_m\right]$ is defined appropriately -- i.e., as a set of certain functions from the set of all monomials to $R$ whose all but finitely many entries are zero. Since the ring structure of $R\left[X_1, \ldots, X_m\right]$ is not used in the theorem or your proof, you don't need $R$ itself to be a ring.)

Comment: One thing that I'm afraid is wrong is that (4) defines a right action of $S_m$ on the tuples, not a left action. Just check associativity and see that it works "the wrong way round". Then again, maybe you never wanted to say that it is a left action. (Though I'd rather not write it in the form $\sigma \cdot \alpha$ then.)